# Duplciate Class Errors on adding Jar file to Android Project

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

I created a new Android project and added a jar file. the moment I tried to build, I got a list of errors, and the build failed, all due to duplicate classes.Can someone help how to fix such issues.

Below is list of few errors I got (due to limitations I attached the full list separetely here https://drive.google.com/file/d/121pkLR9JJV57lhPoT8YAPOEJXijW8BGj/view?usp=sharing):

```
 Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules listenablefuture-1.0 (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0) and smartapi-java-2.1.0 (smartapi-java-2.1.0.jar)
    Duplicate class kotlin.ArrayIntrinsicsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and smartapi-java-2.1.0 (smartapi-java-2.1.0.jar)
    Duplicate class kotlin.BuilderInference found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and smartapi-java-2.1.0 (smartapi-java-2.1.0.jar)
    Duplicate class kotlin.CharCodeJVMKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and smartapi-java-2.1.0 (smartapi-java-2.1.0.jar)
    Duplicate class kotlin.CharCodeKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and smartapi-java-2.1.0 (smartapi-java-2.1.0.jar)
    Duplicate class kotlin.CompareToKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and smartapi-java-2.1.0 (smartapi-java-2.1.0.jar)
    Duplicate class kotlin.ContextFunctionTypeParams found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and smartapi-java-2.1.0 (smartapi-java-2.1.0.jar)
    Duplicate class kotlin.DeepRecursiveFunction found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and smartapi-java-2.1.0 (smartapi-java-2.1.0.jar)
```